# Is Camstudio still an active project?

Tags: video-capture, camtasia

I was just trying to get a quick [free] video record of a screen (with captions), and wanted to use something I've happily used in the past - Camstudio (https://camstudio.org/), but when I go to download it I notice I'm being redirected to a suspect website (http://www.nameghesere.com).

You can't get onto the Camstudio forums without invite - so I thought I'd ask here in case anyone knows.

Has Camstudio been compromised? Is it still a viable [free] solution?

Thanks
Abe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah - I've found another download site for Camstudio (https://sourceforge.net/projects/camstudio/files/latest/download) which includes a warning:

**Notice Regarding Malware:**
The downloads from camstudio.org are known to contain malware.
All downloads from SourceForge are virus scanned. As of this writing there is no malware on the SourceForge downloads for CamStudio.

Perhaps someone should shut down the camstudio.org site.